# Canvas in the middle of Layout i.e ImageView Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, bitmapimage

i am lookin for any way to display canvas at the middle of xml layout i.e displaying canvas on Imageview. i tried but bitmap returns null.

```
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getMeasuredWidth(),img.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);
```

Comment: canvas in middle of xml layout ? what do you mean ?

Comment: imean simple layout having a imageview in the middle and place a canvas on it

Answer (score 0):

Please subclass the ImageView and draw your requirements in onDraw() like below.

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView{

public CustomImageView (Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Bitmap Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getMeasuredWidth(),img.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    c.drawRect(0, 0, 200, 200, paint);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to create bit map.

```
 public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(String path, float scale, boolean filtering){
        Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
        int width = (int)( src.getWidth() * scale + 0.5f);
        int height = (int)( src.getHeight() * scale + 0.5f);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, width, height, filtering);
      }
```

here path is path of your image, then finally put this scaled bit map in your Canvas .